# How can I browse my Tomcat localhost from another computer on the network? and how to run Selenium Script on another Computer?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, tomcat9, localserver

I am trying to access my tomcat LocalHost on another Computer and while accessing it I want my Selenium Script to be run on Another computer .Please Help me regarding this.

(While Running my Selenium code my browser is running on  Tomcat Localhost Computer)

Answer (score 0):

By default I think tomcat starts in 0.0.0.0:80

So it is internet address , you can access the server using network ip from another system in the same network

Eg if network ip is 192.168.1.1 , you can access from another system which has ip 192.168.1.2 , as 192.168.1.1:80

( You can see your ip address by typing ifconfig and ipconfig in linux and windows respectively)

Else edit the ip address using config file and bind the server to your 192.168.1.1 ip

Several connectors are configured, and each connector has an optional "address" attribute where you can set the IP address.

1. Edit `tomcat/conf/server.xml`.
2. Specify a bind address for that connector:

   ```
   <Connector
   port="80"
   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
   address=""
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   redirectPort="8443"
   />
   ```